# ¿Por qué se puede usar un metodo de un objeto de tipo Graphics si no está instanciado?

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe

Estoy aprendiendo a pintar componentes en un `JPanel` dentro de un `JFrame` pero tengo una duda muy grande de cómo funciona el ejemplo del profesor, dicho ejemplo es el siguiente:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class EscribrirEnFrame {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       MarcoConTexto Frame1 = new MarcoConTexto();
       // Creamos el objeto

       Frame1.setVisible(true);
       // Lo hacemos visible
   }

}

class MarcoConTexto extends JFrame {

   public MarcoConTexto() {
       setSize(600, 450);
       setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       setTitle("Marco con texto");
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       PanelConTexto panel1 = new PanelConTexto();
       add(panel1);
   }
 }

class PanelConTexto extends JPanel {

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);
       g.drawString("Hola mundo xd!", 0, 12);
       // el metodo drawString dibuja un string

   }
}
```

El objeto `g` está declarado, sé que pertenece a una clase abstracta y obviamente no puede ser instanciado como tal.

Mi duda es: Si el objeto no es ni puede ser instanciado,¿como es posible que se utilice un método que no es estático para el objeto que, únicamente, esta declarado?

Intente hacer unas pruebas por mi cuenta para entender el funcionamiento en un clase aparte en el método `main` pero no me permite hacer lo mismo.

Comment: Realmente no entiendo bien tu pregunta. A simple vista... Lo que veo es una clase con un método `void` que le pasas como parámetro un tipo `Graphics` llamado **g**. Y en el método, pues el código interno hace referencia a ese objeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Graphics g
```

indica que *g* es una instancia de *Graphics*. Pero que *g* sea una instancia de *Graphics* no significa que se haya tenido que crear a partir de un constructor de la clase *Graphics* (p.ej *new Graphics()*), ya que **todas las instancias de una clase son instancias de sus superclases**.

El ejemplo más claro lo tenemos con *Object*, todos los objetos creados son instancias de *Object* ya que *Object* es una superclase de cualquier clase. Por eso podemos hacer:

```
String str1 = new String("Hola");
Object obj = str1;
```

*str1*, por ser una instancia de una clase que hereda de *Object*, es también una instancia de *Object*.

En este caso, en algún momento la JVM creará una instancia de Graphics a traves de una subclase (no abstracta, por supuesto) de Graphics y lo pasará como parámetro a tu método. Puedes comprobarlo haciendo

```
System.out.println("Clase de g " + g.getClass().getName());
```

Esta forma de trabajar se denomina el **principio de substitución**, que viene a decir, más o menos<sup>1</sup>, que una instancia de una subclase siempre puede usarse exactamente igual que una instancia de una superclase.

Una consecuencia importante es que al hacer una subclase, tienes que asegurarse que su comportamiento sea coherente con el declarado en la superclase. Por ejemplo si haces en tu clase:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (int) (Math.random() * 100);  // Devuelve un número entero aleatorio entre 0 y 99
}
```

esto entra en conflicto con la descripción del método *hashCode()* en *Object* (que exige que el valor devuelto no varíe durante la vida del objeto) y puede causar problemas en código que esperan que el valor sea constante.

---

<sup>1</sup>Hay varias versiones según las restricciones y las condiciones que se exigen.

lo importante es que no es necesario que se cree haciendo *new Graphics([parámetros])* (que, por ser *Graphics* una clase abstracta, sería imposible), sino

Comment: Muchas gracias. No quería quedarme con la laguna de cómo era posible eso antes de avanzar en el curso y con tu respuesta ya lo tengo claro